# How do you reduce string combinations across two columns into one column using the mutate function in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, mutate

Poor data entry has resulted in two columns with similar data that could be combined into one. I've got three groups and  NA, which I want to reduce to two groups and an NA

```
x <- data.frame(
  a= c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 1", NA, "Group 1",NA, "Group 3", "Group 3"),
  b= c("Group 1", NA, NA, "Group 2", "Group 1", NA, NA, "Group 3")
)
x

#The combinations of the group and the desired output: 
#Group 1 + Group 1 = Group 1
#Group 2 + NA = Group 2 
# Group 1 + NA = Group 1 
#NA+NA = NA
#Group 3 + NA = Group 1
#Group 3 + Group 3= Unknown
```

```
x |> 
  dplyr::mutate(Group = case_when(a == c("Group 1")|b == c("Group 1") ~ "Group 1",
                                  a == c("Group 2")|b == c("NA") ~ "Group 2",
                                  a == c("Group 1")|b == c("NA") ~ "Group 2",
                                  a == c("NA")|b == c("NA") ~ NA,
                                  a == c("Group 3")|b == c("NA") ~ "Group 1",
                                  a == c("Group 3")|b == c("Group 3") ~ "Unknown",
  ))
```

The results are below, Group 3 + Group 3 should be an unknown but are being classed as group one.

```
        a       b   Group
1 Group 1 Group 1 Group 1
2 Group 2    <NA> Group 2
3 Group 1    <NA> Group 1
4    <NA> Group 2    <NA>
5 Group 1 Group 1 Group 1
6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
7 Group 3    <NA> Unknown
8 Group 3 Group 3 Group 1
```

I would be grateful for some guidance.

Comment: maybe you can unse and '&' istead of or '|'

Comment: I think you can simplify this to `case_when(a == "Group 3" & b == "Group 3" ~ "Unknown",  a == "Group 3" | b == "Group 3" ~ "Group 1",  .default = coalesce(a, b))`

Comment: I've notice in your code you are using `a == c("NA")|b == c("NA")`, when your data doesn't include `"NA"`s, it has `NA`s. What gives?

Comment: @Mark - because I thought to identify an empty cell, I should write c("NA"), not is.na(a) as I have since learnt from the helpful comments in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
x |> 
  dplyr::mutate(Group = case_when(a == "Group 1" & b == "Group 1" ~ "Group 1",
                                  a == "Group 2" & is.na(b) | is.na(a) & b == "Group 2" ~ "Group 2",
                                  a == "Group 1" & is.na(b) ~ "Group 1",
                                  is.na(a) & is.na(b) ~ NA,
                                  a == "Group 3" & is.na(b) | is.na(a) & b == "Group 3" ~ "Group 1",
                                  a == "Group 3" & b == "Group 3" ~ "Unknown",
  ))
        a       b   Group
1 Group 1 Group 1 Group 1
2 Group 2    <NA> Group 2
3 Group 1    <NA> Group 1
4    <NA> Group 2 Group 2
5 Group 1 Group 1 Group 1
6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
7 Group 3    <NA> Group 1
8 Group 3 Group 3 Unknown
```